# How to enable a button conditioned by a cookie?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, cookies

I am building a web application which can accept both guests and registered users. For registered users, after they have logged in, I want to show a 'Log out' button only for them. I was thinking to make it appear if there is a cookie which indicates that the user is logged in. There is a JSP with a login form which redirects to the GET POST method (servlet) and creates a cookie which is sent to the browser.

My question: How do I correlate the presence of the button with the presence of a cookie that proves the state of the user? Is it on a JSP side or on the servlet side?

Is using cookies the right approach or would it be better to use sessions?

Comment: A question like this without any code is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I actually search through and found a possible answer.

What i can do is get the token using java code in the jsp file from the browser and with that i can get the email of the person who has logged in. By checking if the email is null or not i can see if there is a user logged in.

i can use this example in the jsp file:

```
<% 
  String email = LoginDao.getToken(request.getCookies());
    if (email != null) {
 %>
```

LoginDao.getToken is a method called to separate the email in the cookie.

```
public static String getToken(Cookie[] cookies) throws SQLException {
    String cookieData = null;
    String email = null;
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("token")) {
                cookieData = cookie.getValue();
            }

        }
        if (cookieData != null) {
            email = getEmailCookie(cookieData);
        }
    }
    return email;
}
```

With the help of getEmalCookie:

```
public static String getEmailCookie(String cookieData) throws SQLException {

    String[] splitCookie = cookieData.split("&&&&&");
    String passAndCookieSalt = splitCookie[0];
    String email = splitCookie[1];
    String cookieSalt = splitCookie[2];

    String databaseData = Queries.getPassword(email);

    if(databaseData != null) {
        String[] splitDatabase = databaseData.split("&&&&&");
            if (splitDatabase.length >= 2) {
                String passwordSalt = splitDatabase[1];

                if (Password.hashString(passwordSalt + "&&&&&" + cookieSalt).equals(passAndCookieSalt)) {
                    return email;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```

Queries.getPassword(email) is called to get the email from the database and hash it with (Password.hashString(passwordSalt + "&&&&&" + cookieSalt) and therefore compare it with the pass and cookie salt from the browser.